# What if someone inserts new data into database just before I call for last insert id?

Tags: mysql, sql

When we manage a large database, generally we have multiple tables connected with each other by foreign keys.

Suppose we have a foreign key inside TABLE_2 which is the primary key of TABLE_1. So, whenever we insert new data to TABLE_1 we must get the 'last insert id' and put it in TABLE_2 as a foreign key.

Now let's consider one scenario (regardless of any programming languages) -

> I have inserted one row inside TABLE_1 and then called a method to get the last inserted id. But within the fraction of a second before I call the method someone else also inserted a new row to the same table (TABLE_1).

Now my question is - as I have requested for the last inserted id then which row id will I get? Because the other person has inserted a new row after me.

This question has been kicking my mind for a long time. Please, someone, clear my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, or something else?  Please don't spam tag your question with multiple database tags.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. But all the SQL server works almost the same, right? There is a  method for calling the last insert id in every SQL database (SQLite or MySQL).

Comment: Each RDBMS has its own way to retrieve the last identity value, SQL Server has at least 3 maybe more, and each method works slightly differently. So not only do you need to specify your RDBMS, you need to specify which method you are referring to. That said all methods are well documented and explain their limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for `LAST_INSERT_ID`:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
> ***per-connection*** basis. This means that the value returned by the
> function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
> for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column ***by that
> client***. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
> generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
> that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
> activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
> transactions.

So you don't need to worry about other users inserting data between your insert and getting your last insert id.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You have cleared my doubt.